# Regexp: Horribly slow regexp in perl - how to optimize?

Tags: regular-expression, perl

This:

```
echo BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA |
  perl -pe '/^(.*?B(?:A.*?B){30})A/'
```

takes an astonishing 8 seconds on my machine. I had expected it to take at most a few ms.

This takes < 10 ms:

```
echo BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA |
   perl -pe '/^(.*?B(?:A.*?B){30})A/'
```

How can I make the first go faster?

I will need A and B to be regular expressions i.e. they will not simply be single letters.

Comment: The code blocks for 8 seconds and <10ms seems the exact same... or am I misreading?

Comment: The input is not the same.

Comment: I'm somewhat inclined to vote-to-close this question. This seems far too esoteric to be of any use to anyone in the future. And the proposed solution isn't generic to where it might apply to other situations. What is the use case where someone might need to run such a regex on this type of string? Also what is the expected result? There could be other solutions to the actual problem that is trying to be solved.

Comment: @Patrick It is really not about the use case but more about the problem: What are the techniques you can use, when you stumble upon a regexp+input that is slow? The negative look-ahead followed by . is one of those techniques. (It also serves to validate people that they are not crazy when the same regexp takes ms on one string but 8 seconds on another).

Comment: The actual use case here is for matching 30 sets of parenthesis, except the parenthesis are regexps and they cannot be nested, but I agree that this is not really relevant.

Comment: @OleTange matching parentrhesis is way more effectif done with parsing, though parsing can be done using regular expression, mathing parenthesis is often recursive meaning not properly suitable for recursivity except if your looking for the exact same pattern.

Comment: @Kiwy ... which is why I stress that this is not exactly parenthesis matching but matching on regexp that are user provided and which cannot be nested.

Comment: OK, I'll bite. I'm curious to understand what you are actually trying to match?

Comment: @roaima --recend/--recstart with --regexp for GNU Parallel.

Comment: Not sure what they call this, but 'battling quantifiers' might be a general term. Two instances of the regex atom `.*?` send you into backtracking hell--depending on your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative look-ahead and `.`:

```
perl -pe '/^((?:(?!BA).)*?B(?:A(?:(?!BA).)*?B){30})A/'
```

Not really pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Horribly slow Perl Regex above translated to Raku (still horribly slow, test repeated 2X):*

```perl
~ % echo BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA |
  time raku -pe '/ ^ [ .*? B [A .*? B] ** 30 ] A /;'
BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
raku -pe '/ ^ [ .*? B [A .*? B] ** 30 ] A /;'  49.44s user 0.41s system 100% cpu 49.791 total

~ % echo BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA |
  time raku -pe '/ ^ [ .*? B [A .*? B] ** 30 ] A /;'
BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
raku -pe '/ ^ [ .*? B [A .*? B] ** 30 ] A /;'  52.92s user 0.42s system 100% cpu 53.269 total
```

---

---

*Massive Raku speed-up by adding a single `:` character (prevents local-backtracking, test repeated 2X):*

```perl
~ % echo BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA |
  time raku -pe '/ ^ [ .*? B [A .*? B] **: 30 ] A /;'
BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
raku -pe '/ ^ [ .*? B [A .*? B] **: 30 ] A /;'  0.22s user 0.04s system 138% cpu 0.185 total

~ % echo BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA |
  time raku -pe '/ ^ [ .*? B [A .*? B] **: 30 ] A /;'
BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
raku -pe '/ ^ [ .*? B [A .*? B] **: 30 ] A /;'  0.21s user 0.04s system 139% cpu 0.177 total
```

Raku has a number of ways to turn off backtracking. Backtracking can be turned off globally using the `:ratchet` (or `:r`) adverb. In the code above, backtracking is turned off locally at the point in the Regex where the Regex engine is searching for `30` instances of an atom:

`[A .*? B] ** 30`   *becomes*   `[A .*? B] **: 30`

Final, top-performing Raku regex (and associated references) below.

```perl
raku -pe '/ ^ [ .*? B [A .*? B] **: 30 ] A /;'
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes.html#Preventing_backtracking:_:
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes.html#Ratchet
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes.html